# What makes my kitten fold her tail onto her back

Tags: cats

My cat meavis is a 4 month old kitten that I’m not sure the breed and she loves to fold her tail over her back what and how!? I ask bc my other cat can’t do that

Comment: A photo would help us understand what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

It may be something similar to being double-jointed; there may be a congenital or acquired difference in the kitten's body which lets it be more flexible, which may or may not be an issue. Or it may just be that, like human kids, the kitten is just more flexible than the adult and will lose this ability when it gets older.

If concerned, ask your vet; they may be able to feel what's going on, or if you're willing to spend the money an x-ray might answer the question.

If they weren't sometimes quirky, they wouldn't be cats.